# Depth sorting rectangular polygons, all parts of model axes facing

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d

I'm working on some rendering graphics, I have a model like this, I'm using Java canvas tools and windowing, otherwise independently written.

[image: 3d-frame model]

All the parts are either rectangular polygons or line-segments. As it happens in this model all the polygon parts are aligned with either the x,y or z planes, the xy-origin running from the front corner of the model in the picture. (it is possible to discern the rectangular subdivision of the sides by looking closely at how they appear patched together - but getting rid of this artifact is not addressed here)

I haven't figured out a technique for getting a clean depth-sorting, this one is based on farthest vertex. I've tried some naive techniques and they all have various artifacts to them. I noted binary space partitioning and Newell's algorithm without delving, but have a feeling there should be an easier way in this case, particularly with the condition that all parts are right aligned and parallel to the axes. Any tips on ways about it appreciated

**Update**

I've come up with this idea that might have something going for it

[image: comparison of rectangular polygons]

Given the planar facing constraint, there are 6 possible relationships, (x-x plane), (x-y plane), (x-z plane), (y-y plane), (y-z plane), and (z-z plane).

It is easy to sort two polygons if they share the same plane, the other 3 combinations are shown above (xy on xz), (xy on yz) and (xz on yz), with different order in depth that may occur.

I'm thinking my comparison condition might go something like this, given P1 = polygon1 and P2 = polygon2

```
if (P1 == xy_plane) return min(P1.z, P2.z)
if (P2 == xy_plane) return min(P2.z, P1.z)
if (P1 == xz_plane) return min(P1.y, P2.y)
if (P2 == xz_plane) return min(P2.y, P1.y)
```

P1 or P2 must lie in one of the first two planes, so for problem statement should be sufficient, need to confirm if this approach works

**Update2**

I had some progress along the idea above, and it seems that sorting on polygon matching is doing something interesting, it's been working partially, I'd say it looks easy, but, ... well, I hope you think it is and can tell me what I need to do.

Along the line above, first of all contrary to my assumption, polygons in the same plane are not trivial, they can have several different configurations shown here; parallel and not sharing another axis such as in the first two, or parallel and on the same plane. This sometimes means they don't care which axes they sort on (for pairwise comparison), (and speaks of a deeper side to this pursuit).

[image: polygons on the same plane]

Setting up a series of conditional statements regardless, something along the lines of the suggestion above, which had a brute-force flavor with an extensive series of "if-else", I think eventually I found a correct pair-wise polygon to polygon comparison, so that in this notion one can say certainly if either the subject or the other is the closer.

Working on a single side of the model here, managed to produce something that looks pretty convincing. The process in general feeling close to locking in, but trying to get rid of some final misalignment somehow defiant, as old physical trivias fixing one side the other always gets broken.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to sort relative to the camera direction or just one of the three axes?

Comment: Consider 3 triangles, where each one's top corner is above the wide section of one of the others. Easy to visualize but only a depth buffer can sort that one out :) That said, there may just be a solution for your constrained case.

Comment: I'd like relative to camera, as in the view above, I'm using a focal point A, often the origin, and a moveable camera, vector C. I was thinking, but haven't arrived at a method, that if the camera is in on of the eight xyz octants, the planes would have a preference along each of either +ive or -ive axes, sorting on any of these often give reasonable results, but not fully clean, as yet

Comment: What do you expect from the depth sorting? You want a (sorted) list of your objects s.t. each object is not hidden by previous ones? Then the first question is: is this theoretically possible in your case? (see Jongware's comment) The next question is: can the global sorting be decided locally? (i.e.: given two objects: can you decide their relation indepentently of the other objects?) And if both answers are 'yes', then you want a simple rule/algorithm to decide the relation of two objects, right?

Comment: @coproc Well yes, I'm looking for a clear visual ordering, I suppose a disambiguous transative ordering is the ideal, and from some given view. If I understood Jongware, there are no three polygons in my case that are interleaved and cannot be ordered, and I think this assumption holds for all the elements, whether it's possible to define a disambiguous total ordering, I don't know, if you can prove it's not it would certainly be worth something ...

Comment: @coproc Also, whether an ordering can be effected on pairwise comparison, or would need some heuristic .. well, I don't know, and is an excellent line of enquiry. Regaring Jongware's insight, I don't think it actually applies - I don't think three triangles be planar facing and also interleaving - can you prove me wrong on this?

Comment: Maybe worth stating that my polyogons will never overlap if they are in the same plane. Based on visual experience it always seems very obvious, so a counter-example could be valuable

Comment: Frankly, if the idea is to gain speed, using a shader is the way to go. If not, the order of your algorithm will always be O(N²) (pairwise comparisons), and would eventually slow to a crawl with too many surfaces to draw. Besides, ordering the surfaces for a painting algorithm is only possible if none of them intersect by more than a side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me add some observations:

The conditions that

- all polygon sides are parallel to an axis and that
- the polygons are not intersecting

are not enough to ensure the existance of a global depth sorting of the polygons - as can be seen with this example of three rectangles:

[image: depths interleaving]

Also the relative depth order of two objects can depend on other objects as can be seen in this 2D example, where the depth order of the objects A and B, which are not hiding each other, depends on the position of object C:

[image]

So going for a global depth sorting of the objects does not seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the general problem, where the sides are not generally parallel to the axes, may be easier.

Figure out the line of intersection (call it L) of planes containing the 2 faces. Now, assuming the faces don't intersect, each face will be entirely on one side of L.

Now find a vector V perpendicular to L, that passes through the camera. The visible face is the one that is at a lower angle to V. You can compare the angles using some cross products and dot products.

You can simplify this a lot for the parallel-to-axes case (finding L and V is trivial).

For Line segments, using an arbitrary plane containing the line should work.

For coplanar faces, it doesn't matter, because one will never obscure the other.

You need to special-case the parallel-face case.

This algorithm is O(N^2) in the number of faces, You need to do pairwise comparisions. Using the depth buffer as someone suggested may be more viable if you have lots of faces.